# android get formatted string via webservice

Tags: android

In my android app, I send an HTTP POST Request and get a **responseString** like this:

```
Titel<br /><div style="color: #D88948">Description</div>
```

this string I would like to set in a textview with the same style.
I know that I have to convert the `<br />` to perform a line break.

For this I use this code:

```
Html.fromHtml(responseString.replace("\n", "<br />")));
```

but how can I apply the font color for my description?

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/txtview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargePopupMenu"/>
```

**AutoComplete**

```
responseString = "Titel<br /><div style="color: #D88948">Description</div>";
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                this,
                R.layout.autocomplete, R.id.txtresponseString,
                responseString 
        );
        TextView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: post your xml layout code.

Comment: you can give a android:textcolor here in textview. set hex code color whichever u want to set.

Comment: no I can't - if i do it like this, the whole text get this color. but i only would like to change the color of the description as in the response string. Titel is default black, and only Description get another Color

Comment: fromHtml does not support the `style` attribute. see if you can convince your server to send tags among those: https://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html

Answer (score -1):

to do that you must put the description inside his own text view by splitng the server response into two differents texviews

Comment: and how can i do this with an Autocomplete Textview? i would like to have 2 lines in the dropdown - first line the title with black color, second line description in another color. i know how i can create the xml file for this. but how can i call the first and second line of the dropdown. my code for this at the moment is this (look post 1)

Comment: you can get the parameters insithe the adapter and make whatever you want there inside the function getView

Comment: can you explain me, how i do this - this is my first time with autocomplete and adapter

Comment: can you post your adapter code so that i can have a good start point to try to help you ? or the above code is the complete code of your adapter ?

Comment: the above code is my complete code for my adapter :/

Comment: as i can see there is no way to update dynamically a dropdown item instead than create your own adapter but even there you'll still have to create two differents textviews to handle the color argument dynamicallu coming from the server

Comment: i have no problem with an own adapter, to solve my problem. but the big question is: HOW? ^^

Comment: no need for separate textviews, that's what spannables are for.